# Steam shopping cart is emptying itself

Tags: steam

I added about 10 games into my shopping cart, then I wanted to add some money to my steam wallet and had some credit card issues. After I solved the issues and added money to my wallet, I was back to the steam homepage and went to open my shopping cart.

However, there were no games in the shopping cart and I do not remember some of the games I added. Is there a solution or trick? I tried to look at my browser history and go back to the shopping cart but still no games appear.

Comment: I guess the problem was that adding money to your wallet is implemented as shopping, so it cleared your shopping cart and added the "money" that you "bought". I don't think you can get the cart back, it was probably saved in a cookie or something

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But It isn't a good way to purchase money for wallet.

Comment: I'm not saying it is a bad way to do it, I do it, too. I just wanted to explain what probably happened to your shopping cart.

Comment: I guess it's either a bug or a deliberate safety feature - to prevent a user accidentally buying the stuff in his cart just because he added money to his wallet.  I would tend to agree that a better solution would be to somehow "cache" the contents of the cart so they can be restored after the wallet purchase goes through.  You can write an email to Steam support to complain about the issue and see what they say about it.

Comment: Sorry to potentially be stating a stupid suggestion, but shopping carts are device-based, not account-based.  So, if you had the cart saved on your phone and then moved to your PC, it would be empty.  Using the same device will show your cart is still available.

Comment: @Steve-O Yes I will send an email about the issue.

Comment: @Batophobia I didn't move from phone to PC. But Your suggestion would be helpful for some other people.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's because you've added funds to your wallet. I've added money to my wallet, and my cart was just as fine. However, it empties itself at some point in time, probably according to a specific schedule or when Steam updates its policy, etc. Mine's got emptied by Steam perhaps just as yours, about a day or two ago. But who knows, Valve works in mysterious ways.

Comment: Elapsed time between adding games to shopping cart and adding money to my wallet is not one or two days. About 1 hour at most.